# A problem on counting total number of ways of arranging numbers in a grid.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, combinations

Let $N$ be the number of ways to place the integers $1$ through $12$ in the $12$ cells of a $2×6$ grid so that for
any two cells sharing a side, the difference between the numbers in those cells is not divisible by $3$. One
way to do this is shown below.

[image]

What is $N$ ?

I tried by taking congruence modulo $3$. Taking $6$ cases of arranging $0,1,2$ in $a_{11},a_{12},a_{21}$.

> $a_{ij}$ represents element of $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column.

And tried to make a recurrence, but nothing went good. I tried making cases but the were very much which need atleast 2 hours to solve.

Can someone help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider the reduced problem of arranging 0, 1, 2.

Observations/hints towards a solution. If you're stuck, explain what you're thinking.

1. Show that each column has distinct entries.
2. We label each column with the entry that doesn't appear. IE If the first column is $(0, 1)$, then we label it 2.

   - Suppose there are $a/b/c$ columns labelled $0/1/2$. Show that $a=b=c=2$.
3. Conversely, suppose we're given any order of the 6 labels, with 0/1/2/ each appearing twice:

   - Show that for any 2 neighboring labels, their columns are uniquely determined up to switching of the rows.
   - Show that the arrangement of 0/1/2 is uniquely determined by the first column.
   - Hence for each order, there are $\underline{ \quad}$ possibilities to place 4 each of the 0/1/2 according to the restrictions.
4. Since there are ${ 6 \choose 2, 2, 2} $ possible orders of the labels, there are $\underline{ \quad}$ ways to place the 0/1/2.

   - Hence, for the original problem, there are $\underline{ \quad}$ ways to place  1 to 12.